# What is the difference between "talento" and "talentoso"?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, adjetivos, sustantivos

In my Spanish textbook it has the following examples:

> I think you must be very talented
>   Creo que debe ser muy talentoso
>
> You are very talented
>   Tienes mucho talento

Why does one use *talento* and the other *talentoso*. What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Talento](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/talento) is a *noun*

> 1.m. Conjunto de facultades o capacidades tanto artísticas como intelectuales: "tienes talento como escritor."
>   2. Persona muy inteligente o destacada en alguna ciencia o actividad:
>   talento de la música.

while [talentoso](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/talentoso) is an *adjective*

> adj. Que tiene talento o ingenio:

Comment: Indeed. It's the same difference between _you are very **talented**_ and _you've got **talent**_.